# how to set scroll function on select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set scroll function on select box so that whenever i scroll , an alert will be there . i am not able to set that .scroll function of jquery on select. Please tell me how to set it. May be i am doing some mistake in my code.

Code:

```
<div class="dropdown col-xs-4">
  <input list="d1" id="search" name="d1" class="form-control input-xs" placeholder="Search by">
    <!-- <datalist id="d1"> -->
    <select id="d1">
      {{#each data1}}
    <option class="form-control" > {{TradeName}} </option>
     {{/each}}
   </select>
   <!-- </datalist> -->
</div>
```

Js file:

```
      $( "#d1" ).scroll(function() {
  console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

Comment: What's the point? Why would you need to know when the options list is scrolled?

Comment: ^ Plus, you could use Dropdown components such as the one available with Bootstrap, if you really need it, for cases where infinite scrolling is desired.

Comment: i need it for lazy loading. i need to know , when scroll reaches bottom point of select box during scrolling.

Comment: Use onscroll which execute a JavaScript when a <div> element is being scrolled.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava Still not working

Comment: You said "whenever i scroll , an alert will be there ", first thing you wont be able to scroll and if not this, where exactly you want to display the alert message.

Comment: @Engineerheart You could load the whole dropdown on onfocus or click of select element. Though select supports all dom events somehow browser seems to treat dom scroll with preference over user defined scroll event for select element. since showing next set of options is primary func of scroll.(just what I am thinking at this point) I am doing more research on the same topic. it is definitely an interesting point to learn. Another approach i am thinking is lets say you prepopulate dropdown with 5 options to begin with you can couple it with onfocus/click to check if length is 5&load more

Comment: Also just google and research more. there are a lot of options available to work around the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm afraid decent UI experience was gone at the moment a drop list began to need lazy-loading. You should not load the entire database to a single drop list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("d1").addEventListener("scroll", scroll);

function scroll() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Scrolled";
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="d1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" >
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>f</option>
    <option>g</option>
    <option>h</option>
      </select>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I just edited the code. As work around you can try this. The text will get display when you do scroll down. This is not such a good approach but for the time being you can use this.

Comment: It is working but it increases data without limit. i.e i want to show 5 more data when scroll reach bottom but it showing unusual limit of data . like first time it shows 5 then next time it increase data by 20 then 3rd time it do by 125 and so on. I just want to show my data increment by 5 everytime whenever scroll reaches bottom.

Comment: For that you need to write your logic on how many data you want on scroll. You can add your logic in the onmousedown event. That might solve the problem.

Comment: This logic i have used. 

       

        $(window).scroll(function() {
          console.log("scrolling");
         if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
             lmt_val = lmt_val + 5;
            //  alert("scrolled");

       Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
         var value1 = demoData.find({},{limit:lmt_val}).fetch();
         SessionStore.set("jkl",value1);
       }, 1000);

         }
      });

Comment: do u know how to set scroll bar on datalist?

Comment: Set overflow property on that, using CSS.

Comment: You cannot do scroll on a datalist because it is a bug on the Chromium bug tracker, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375637.

Comment: hmm... anything else similar to datalist which i can use instead of datalist?